# PHP - Unexpected behaviour when added SSL to TCP socket

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, tcp, websocket

I've developed PHP WebSocket server, that uses HTTP protocol for the handshake. Everything worked fine.

The problem started when I wanted to add SSL layer. When I enable it HTTP frames arrives split into 2 pieces - I need to call read function twice to read 2nd piece:

1. First letter of HTTP header (G)
2. The rest of the header

Without SSL everything works fine. I've tried a lot of modifications but with no results.
Any ideas?

Listing of read function:

> ```
> protected function read($toRead = 1400) {
>   $return = "";
>   for (;;) {
>       if ($toRead < Config::$socket['chunk_size']) {
>           $length = $toRead;
>       } else {
>           $length = Config::$socket['chunk_size'];
>       }
>       $sData = fread($this->socket, $length);
>       if ($sData == false) return false;
>       $toRead = $toRead - $length;
>       $return .= $sData;
>       if ($toRead == 0) break;
>   }
>   var_dump($return);
>     return $return;
> }
> ```

SSLContext:

```
protected function createSSLContext() {
    $context = stream_context_create();
    if (Config::$ssl['switch']) {
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', Config::$ssl['filename']);     
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
        stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
        if (isset(Config::$ssl['passphrase'])) { 
            stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', Config::$ssl['passphrase']);
        }
    }
    $this->context = $context;
}
```

Comment: no errors displayed at all ?

Comment: did you enable "Display Errors" ?

Comment: yep, ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

Answer (score 0):

I've been using stunnel instead, but still cannot find the solution for the problem.